# excel vba check if any cell in range is empty

Tags: excel, vba, range, cell

I need check if any cell in Range is empty, using VBA in Excel. If so, then write a messing box.
 I have data similar to this

> ID    ColumnB
>
> 1     a
>
> 2     aa
>
> 3
>
> 4     ab

I tried many codes, but always it write the messing box, even when the columnB has no empty cell.

One of the code is

```
For Each cell In Range(Range("A4").End(xlDown).Offset, Range("A4").End(xlDown).End(xlUp)).Offset(0, 1)
If IsEmpty(cell) = True Then
    GoTo Done1
End If
Done1:
MsgBox "In column B are empty cells.", vbInformation
Next cell
```

I have data from row 4 and Column A doesn't have empty cell (that is why I use Offset())
I always see messing box 5 times (because the range has 5 rows), even when I modify the data, so ColumnB doesn't have any empty cells.
I also tried

```
If cell.Value = "" Then
```

Or

```
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(Range("A4").End(xlDown).Offset, Range("A4").End(xlDown).End(xlUp)).Offset(0, 1)) = 0 Then
'    GoTo Done3
```

And many others, but nothing work.
Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Use `SpecialCells` with celltype Empty as a possibility. Or else a `Application.CountIf()`. And getting a last used row using `xlUp` is more reliable. There should be plenty examples around if you give it a quick search =)

Comment: What is the purpose of that "goto"? I don't understand it. It is writing the message box everytime because you included it in your for loop. There is no condition that checks if the msgbox should be displayed.

Comment: IcesHay, thank you. Since I moved msgBox into if statement and removed GoTo it works. Thank you